# How do I keep a VS Lightswitch Combo box from timing out?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-lightswitch

In a Lightswitch Desktop Client (C#) application I have a List/Detail screen where I add participants to a class roster.  This application has been in use for more than a year and has worked fine but now the "Participants" table has grown to more than 2500 records. The List/Detail screen for "Classes" has a sub form for "RosterAttendences". In the RosterAttendences sub form there is a combo box/pulldown to list all of the participants in the Participants table so that the data entry person can add records for individuals to the roster for that class. In the test instance on VS it works fine but with live application/data it times out. First the spinning blue circle will appear as soon the down arrow is selected and eventually (more than a minute) it will stop and be replaced with a red X.  All of the other combo boxes in the application function properly and the current work around is to add the classes in the participant's profile which also is working properly.  Is there a way to optimize the combo box so that it does not time out?

Comment: Unrelated note about the tag [tag:visual-studio]. If you read the description, it says *DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio.*, so it should not be used in this question. Consider adding a C# tag.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.*

Comment: The desired behavior is to not have it time out and the solution, even though the underlying code is c#, will be executed within Lightswitch. As Lightswitch is being retired by Lightswitch and not included in newer versions of VS chances that I get assistance here are slim. I know there are people out there who can help.  Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Adding the C# tag: good; there are lightswitch tags as well which might help. *"in the question itself"* means that the information needs to be put it in the question itself, not a comment. And the *"shortest code necessary to reproduce"* is still unsatisfied - we need a [mcve]. As it stands, I suspect this question will remain unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the field from Auto Complete to Modal Window Picker when more than say 100 records. You get searching, sorting and paging but there are usability concerns as it will take more mouse clicks but it's the only way to handle large amounts of data.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/88001cd8-539c-47cd-8599-f1703d2a1cd9/how-do-i-optimize-a-combo-box-in-a-desktop-client-app-created-with-lightswitch-c?forum=lightswitch

Answer (score 0):

If time is not an issue you might increase ClientTimeout

Comment: The number of records in the database has increased a lot and the solution outlined below increases the number of clicks to get the record saved but it is much faster.  Before it completely failed data entry people were waiting 5 seconds or more for the dropdown to populate. However, thank you for your help.